# Permission denied when using nginx

Tags: nginx, stat

I started nginx in alamalinux 9.1 and when I visit the site, I got 404 errors, and I also found some errors in log files like `2023/05/06 16:14:33 [crit] 248989#248989: *15900 stat() "/root/device_reservation_mgmt/html/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied)`.

Maybe it's the `/root/device_reservation_mgmt/` problem I thought. So I tested it with `stat` command. I also tried to `chmod 755 /root/device_reservation_mgmt/`, even `chown -R nginx:nginx /root/device_reservation_mgmt/`, but it didn't pass for `stat` test.

The following is the shell logs I tried.

```
[root@localhost device_reservation_mgmt]# ll /root/device_reservation_mgmt/html/
total 112
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   644 May  6 16:11 _app.config.js
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 61440 May  6 16:11 assets
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   894 May  6 16:11 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2893 May  6 16:11 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1311 May  6 16:11 index.html.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7367 May  6 16:11 logo.png
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root    32 May  6 16:11 resource
[root@localhost device_reservation_mgmt]#
[root@localhost device_reservation_mgmt]# chown -R nginx:nginx /root/device_reservation_mgmt/html/
[root@localhost device_reservation_mgmt]#
[root@localhost html]# ll
total 112
-rw-r--r-- 1 nginx nginx   644 May  6 16:11 _app.config.js
drwxr-xr-x 2 nginx nginx 61440 May  6 16:11 assets
-rw-r--r-- 1 nginx nginx   894 May  6 16:11 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r-- 1 nginx nginx  2893 May  6 16:11 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 nginx nginx  1311 May  6 16:11 index.html.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 nginx nginx  7367 May  6 16:11 logo.png
drwxr-xr-x 4 nginx nginx    32 May  6 16:11 resource
[root@localhost html]# cd ..
[root@localhost device_reservation_mgmt]#
[root@localhost device_reservation_mgmt]# sudo -u nginx stat  /root/device_reservation_mgmt/html
stat: cannot statx '/root/device_reservation_mgmt/html': Permission denied
[root@localhost device_reservation_mgmt]#
[root@localhost ~]# sudo -u nginx stat  /root/device_reservation_mgmt
stat: cannot statx '/root/device_reservation_mgmt': Permission denied
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# sudo -u nginx stat  /root/
  File: /root/
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 100663361   Links: 59
Access: (0550/dr-xr-x---)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-05-06 16:21:16.188246512 +0800
Modify: 2023-05-06 16:18:10.295282579 +0800
Change: 2023-05-06 16:18:10.295282579 +0800
 Birth: 2020-02-11 13:12:10.898000000 +0800
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# ll -d device_reservation_mgmt/
drwxr-xr-x. 8 nginx nginx 247 May  6 16:21 device_reservation_mgmt/
[root@localhost ~]# ll -d /root
dr-xr-x---. 59 root root 4096 May  6 16:18 /root
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# chmod a+x /root/device_reservation_mgmt/
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# stat --format '%a' /root
550
[root@localhost ~]# stat --format '%a' /root/device_reservation_mgmt/
755
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# chmod 550 /root/device_reservation_mgmt/ 
[root@localhost ~]# sudo -u nginx stat  /root/device_reservation_mgmt/
stat: cannot statx '/root/device_reservation_mgmt/': Permission denied
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost device_reservation_mgmt]# cp -r html/ /opt/html
[root@localhost device_reservation_mgmt]# sudo -u root stat  /opt/html
  File: /opt/html
  Size: 132         Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 2325445     Links: 4
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-05-06 16:28:50.883780094 +0800
Modify: 2023-05-06 16:28:51.318794001 +0800
Change: 2023-05-06 16:28:51.318794001 +0800
 Birth: 2023-05-06 16:28:50.883780094 +0800
[root@localhost device_reservation_mgmt]#
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, maybe the `other` permission of `/root` did not have `x` bit.

And also pay attention to the location of `stat` and the cwd, they have an effect on the result of `stat`.

```
[root@localhost device_reservation_mgmt]# sudo -u nginx stat html
  File: html
  Size: 132         Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 302504300   Links: 4
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-05-06 16:28:50.883780094 +0800
Modify: 2023-05-06 16:11:09.974794787 +0800
Change: 2023-05-07 12:26:48.132876001 +0800
 Birth: 2023-05-06 16:11:09.932793439 +0800
[root@localhost device_reservation_mgmt]# cd /opt
[root@localhost opt]# sudo -u nginx stat /root/device_reservation_mgmt/html/
stat: cannot statx '/root/device_reservation_mgmt/html/': Permission denied
[root@localhost opt]# cd /root
[root@localhost ~]# sudo -u nginx stat /root/device_reservation_mgmt/html/
stat: cannot statx '/root/device_reservation_mgmt/html/': Permission denied
[root@localhost ~]# sudo -u nginx stat device_reservation_mgmt/html/
stat: cannot statx 'device_reservation_mgmt/html/': Permission denied
[root@localhost ~]# ll -d .
dr-xr-x---. 59 root root 4096 May  7 12:31 .
[root@localhost ~]# chmod a+x .
[root@localhost ~]# sudo -u nginx stat /root/device_reservation_mgmt/html/
  File: /root/device_reservation_mgmt/html/
  Size: 132         Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 302504300   Links: 4
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-05-06 16:28:50.883780094 +0800
Modify: 2023-05-06 16:11:09.974794787 +0800
Change: 2023-05-07 12:26:48.132876001 +0800
 Birth: 2023-05-06 16:11:09.932793439 +0800
[root@localhost ~]# cd /opt/
[root@localhost opt]# sudo -u nginx stat /root/device_reservation_mgmt/html/
  File: /root/device_reservation_mgmt/html/
  Size: 132         Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 302504300   Links: 4
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-05-06 16:28:50.883780094 +0800
Modify: 2023-05-06 16:11:09.974794787 +0800
Change: 2023-05-07 12:26:48.132876001 +0800
 Birth: 2023-05-06 16:11:09.932793439 +0800
[root@localhost opt]#
```